# Xy curves not obeying round frames

Tags: graphs, xy-pic

I am trying to draw the Frucht graph in with Xy-pic, using the polygon extension. The natural way to make curved inside edges (`"origin" ; "destination" **\crv{"center"}`) doesn't quite reach the destination, leaving unsightly gaps on some of the edges

My workaround is to drop an empty line between the last (in my case, the only) control point, and then use `?>` to explicitly set the destination at the border of the vertex.

Why is this happening, and are there better workarounds?

Example and render (pdflatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,poly]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{xy}
  /r4.5pc/:
  {\xypolygon12"A"{[o]=<14pt>[F-]{\xypolynode}}},
  "A0"*\txt{Good},
  "A0";"A1"**@{},"A4";?>**\crv{"A0"},
  "A0";"A2"**@{},"A9";?>**\crv{~**\dir{.}"A0"},
  "A0";"A3"**@{},"A5";?>**\crv{"A0"},
  "A0";"A6"**@{},"A8";?>**\crv{"A0"},
  "A0";"A7"**@{},"A11";?>**\crv{"A0"},
  "A0";"A10"**@{},"A12";?>**\crv{"A0"},
\end{xy} \qquad \begin{xy}
  /r4.5pc/:
  {\xypolygon12"A"{[o]=<14pt>[F-]{\xypolynode}}},
  "A0"*\txt{Bad},
  "A1";"A4"**\crv{"A0"},
  "A2";"A9"**\crv{~**\dir{.}"A0"},
  "A3";"A5"**\crv{"A0"},
  "A6";"A8"**\crv{"A0"},
  "A7";"A11"**\crv{"A0"},
  "A10";"A12"**\crv{"A0"},
\end{xy}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Minimum working example, rendered.]

Comment: I think you'll be a lot better of switching to tikz. Much easier to get help and a much more understandable syntax.

Comment: Is your problem solved with my answer? If yes, please consider to [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it in order to close this post. If not, please tell us, what is missing.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I am looking for an explanation of Xy's behaviour in the 'Bad' snippet. Your answer gives a Tikz implementation of a drawing I am already able to draw.

Answer (score 2):

daleif is right to suggest Ti*k*Z here in his comment. Therefor, I provide a Ti*k*Z solution. This one requires LuaLaTeX. If you want to continue using pdfLaTeX for your main document, you could compile this one here in a standalone document and include the resulting PDF to your paper. For a pure pdfLaTeX version, you should have a look on the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual where you will find other solutions than mine.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[simple necklace layout, node distance=1.5cm, nodes={circle,draw,minimum width=0.8cm}, horizontal=6 to 1]
{ 1--12--11--10--9--8--7--6--5--4--3--2--1, 
    5--[bend right]3, % you can write bend right='some measure' in order to get custom arcs.
    4--[bend right]1,
    6--[bend left]8,
    7--[bend left]11,
    10--[bend left]12,
    9--[bend left, dotted]2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why is lualatex needed? (haven't tested the code)

Comment: @daleif "Unlike the rest of pgf and Ti*k*Z, which is implemented purely in TeX, the graph drawing algorithms
are simply too complex to be implemented directly in TeX. Instead, the programming language Lua is used
by the graph drawing library [...]" - Till Tantau in his great `texdoc pgf`

Comment: And say the op need this for an article, what is the likelihood that the journal supports lualatex? Just a note of warning for the archive.

Comment: @daleif Of course, but I am using LuaLaTeX since a while without any problems. This warning could be written below any Lua- and XeLaTeX answer on this site. If the journal compatibility is an issue, the OP might want to produce this graph as a standalone and include the result to her/his paper.

Comment: Exactly, but how many casual users coming by via google thinks about this? Whan a lualatex solution is given to a pdflatex problem (as mentioned by the OP), I think a note is in order.

Comment: @daleif added some words. Haven't seen the pdfLaTeX constraint in the OP. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: No problem (just noticed it when I double checked). But the image is not that hard to do manually anyway, once you have the circles placed and labelled.